# Angular directive populate children

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a directive that binds an object model that can include options.  If it's applied to a widget that supports options I'd like it to automatically populate the options.  However, the closest I've come is inserting the options as siblings of the directive host.

Currently functional, but the ngFor is logically unnecessary:

```
        <dropdown [ionSetting]="name" #modeSetting="ionSetting">
          <option *ngFor="let option of modeSetting.options" [value]="option">{{ option }}</option>
        </dropdown>
```

this should be good enough:

```
<dropdown [ionSetting]="name" #modeSetting="ionSetting"></dropdown>
```

To do this I would need the directive to do something along the lines of this:

```
updateHost() {
      const optionFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Option);
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
      this.options.forEach(option => {
          const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(optionFactory);
          component.instance.value = option;
          // insert 'option' text
      });
}
```

But this generates siblings:

```
<dropdown [ionSetting]="name"></dropdown>
<option [value]="option"></option>
```

Can I dynamically insert those options as children of the host?

Comment: I supouse you are looking for Renderer2, see https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/ or the official https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: Not sure if it can be done using directive. Anyway you can achieve the same result by creating your own component with same inputs as dropdown component and with html template similiar to the one from your first code snippet.

Comment: @eliseo I did try the renderer but it didn't seem to trigger change detection or normal angular life cycles.

Comment: @wilhelm, I should have stated that this directive two way binds a dozen widgets, so components arent ideal.